# How to display all entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have got List of all entities from a table in a database by the method:

```
public Collection<? extends Product> getAllProducts() throws SQLException {
        Session session = Hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        products = session.createCriteria(Product.class).list();
        return products;
    }
```

I want to display `Product.name` for all elements from given collection. How it can be done in `jsp` page?

Comment: -1 This question is not about hibernate and not about spring-mvc- it is about displaying elements of a collection in a JSP page - and has been answered a couple of times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have put the `product` list in `modelmap` inside your controller.

Access the same inside Jsp through your `command object`.

**Jsp Code**

```
<c:forEach var="product" begin="0" step="1" items="${products}">
     <td>${product.name}</td>
 </c:forEach>
```